# How to extract an image from a url (Article)

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, url, uiimageview

How do I extract an image from a url and place it in a image view?

The code below only works if the url is STRICTLY an IMAGE ONLY from Google images etc.

How do I extract an image from an Article from the Huffington post, LA Times etc.??? If I replace the url with a article from the Huffington post the code doesn't work.

```
NSString *string = @"http://efdreams.com/data_images/dreams/lion/lion-   03.jpg";
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]]];
```

Note: I asked a similar question before but I realized my code was correct but the url is the problem

Comment: Your question is far too broad but basically you need to parse the resulting HTML and find the relevant image URL then load the image from the found URL.

Comment: I would add to @maddy's comment: the task may be complicated by the fact that many images have a relative URL. So you will have to find the absolute URL path and combine them (sometime not a trivial task). Furthermore, in many websites, the content is added at load time through Java or PHP scripts. In this case the image URL may not be  immediately evident in the html code. You may have better luck using some scraping API.